# Where to handle computed properties with Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

when using Redux, the store is supposed to be the single source of truth, and to have no redundancy. Suppose part of the store represents people, who have a name and an age. A person class in traditional object-oriented programming might look something like this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(first, last, birthday) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    get_fullname() { // ... //}
    get_age() { // ... //}
}
```

However, methods aren't allowed on objects in the Redux store. So, where should these "methods" be implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. In reducers.

   Not sure where you got the 'no redundancy in the store' rule. It is perfectly valid to have the results of computations to be kept alongside source data in the store (albeit in such simple case as concatenating name and surname that might not be the best approach)
2. In selectors.

   Selectors are functions used to fetch specific subbranches from the store. They can also perform computations on them before returning. [See this chapter in redux' documentation for some examples](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html).

   This, with some memoization where needed, is I suppose the better solution of the two.

Answer (score 6):

You can compute this kind of state on-demand inside your `connect` functions with a *selector*.

```
function getFullName(state) {
  return `${state.first} ${state.last}`;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    fullName: getFullName(state)
  };
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Check out [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), a selector library that is designed to work well with Redux.

*Technically* there's no rule saying that you can't handle it in your reducer, then store the precomputed state inside your store, but you'll have to remember to update it each and every time the dependent properties change.

*Generally* you'll end up with simpler code if you keep redundant data out of your store and using selectors allows you to write and share the on-demand computations between your components as and when you need them.