# How to put queries in ArcGIS esri search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have my own query in search, How can i disable the default search function in ArcGIS search widget and apply mine?

my current code

```
const location = () => {
   const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'arcgis-light-gray',
       
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        center: [123.5504, 12.3574], // Longitude, latitude
        container: mapDiv.current,
        map: map,
        zoom: 2, // Zoom level
        ui: {
          components: ["attribution"] // removes default widgets except for attribution
       }
      });
      var zoom = new Zoom({
        view: view,
        layout: "vertical"
     });
     view.ui.add(zoom, "bottom-right");
     
      view
        .when((r) => {})
        .then(() => {
          mapDiv.current = view;
          search();
        }); 
    }
const search = () => {
      const searchWidget = new Search();

      mapDiv.current.ui.add(searchWidget, { position: "top-left", index: 2 });

}
```

this is the sample search widget in arcGIS, I want to override the search function, that the only thing that can be searched is the data in my query and it will appear just like in the picture

[image]

resource

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html

Comment: what is the default search behavior and what behavior you want in place of it?

Comment: in arcGIS search widget there is already have a search function that if you tried to type there is a suggestion appearing, and i want to override that. I want to override the search function using my query, but i dont know how to override it

Comment: @K450 I just updated the question

Comment: have you tried providing an array to `suggestions` property?

Comment: @K450, no. I dont know how. I dont know how to override the suggestions

Comment: wait so you want to override the source for your search. Like user should only be able to search from the data you provide?

Comment: Yes exactly !!! @K450

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240193/discussion-between-k450-and-kaito).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom `SearchSource` that pulls suggestions and results from your data, and set it as a source for your `searchWidget`.

#### Things you need to implement:

- `SearchSource` - search source that uses your data.

  - `getSuggestions` [returns `promise`] - Proivdes list of suggestions from your source
  - `getResults` [returns `promise`] - Provides list of search results from your source.

#### Implementation:

<sup>I modified this [sample code for search widget with custom source](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/?sample=widgets-search-customsource) provided with official docs</sup>

As you can see that `getSuggestions` and `getResults` both returns a `promise` as it is designed to access remote data with api's. But as your data is stored locally, you need to create a `promise` object that resolves to your data.

##### Test Data you provided me:

```js
const test_data = {
    allIBLocations: {
      data: [
        {
          id: 'e53be02e-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'Revere - 2',
          externalId: '547e2f43-b950-4b5e-ada4-7fcc110a3785',
          ownerId: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          owner: {
            id: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:00.787Z',
          ibLocationType: {
            name: 'Shared Office',
          },
          ibLocationTypeId: 'e53bca08-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          capacity: null,
          phoneNumber: null,
          address: {
            street1: 'Nitzsche Burg',
            street2: 'Emiliano Camp',
            city: 'Rowlandtown',
            state: 'Kentucky',
            zipCode: '41738',
            country: 'Kuwait',
          },
          geoCode:{
            latitude:-23.0633,
            longitude:15.0875
          }
          // geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: 'e53be45c-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'Jersey City - 4',
          externalId: '1fb7c170-f794-4c85-9a3b-57b8013a2821',
          ownerId: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          owner: {
            id: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:00.788Z',
          ibLocationType: {
            name: 'Warm Site',
          },
          ibLocationTypeId: 'e53bcf80-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          capacity: null,
          phoneNumber: null,
          address: {
            street1: 'Madisen Club',
            street2: 'Cyrus Courts',
            city: 'East Breanamouth',
            state: 'Kentucky',
            zipCode: '05565-8531',
            country: 'Solomon Islands',
          },
          geoCode:{
            latitude:51.6617,
            longitude:-4.5789
          }
          // geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: 'e53be510-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'Wellington - 5',
          externalId: '479e2dc0-b55d-42fd-978b-9d9086216a5f',
          ownerId: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          owner: {
            id: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:00.788Z',
          ibLocationType: {
            name: 'Hospital',
          },
          ibLocationTypeId: 'e53bbf40-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          capacity: null,
          phoneNumber: null,
          address: {
            street1: 'Carter Pass',
            street2: 'Gutmann Brooks',
            city: 'Paterson',
            state: 'New Jersey',
            zipCode: '79928-2470',
            country: 'Cyprus',
          },
          geoCode: {
            latitude: 51.0899,
            longitude: 67.9272,
          },
        },
        {
          id: 'e53be7e0-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'Doral - 9',
          externalId: 'b096ed12-fed2-4a9b-8e61-5c2639b7b7d8',
          ownerId: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          owner: {
            id: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:00.789Z',
          ibLocationType: {
            name: 'Warehouse',
          },
          ibLocationTypeId: 'e53bcc24-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          capacity: null,
          phoneNumber: null,
          address: {
            street1: 'Koelpin Lodge',
            street2: 'Ana Tunnel',
            city: 'Carsonside',
            state: 'Maine',
            zipCode: '44431',
            country: 'Guatemala',
          },
          geoCode: {
            latitude: 0.181,
            longitude: 47.7937,
          },
          //  "geoCode": null
        },
        {
          id: 'e53bec7c-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'Bossier City - 13',
          externalId: '486d4838-bb19-4b29-b4d0-1b492762ebe8',
          ownerId: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          owner: {
            id: '494bd1c4-6d28-4a42-9d98-515129fde2b9',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:00.790Z',
          ibLocationType: {
            name: 'Hospital',
          },
          ibLocationTypeId: 'e53bbf40-4cdb-11ec-81d3-0242ac130003',
          capacity: null,
          phoneNumber: null,
          address: {
            street1: 'Lakin Throughway',
            street2: 'Zulauf Island',
            city: 'Casa Grande',
            state: 'Illinois',
            zipCode: '68798',
            country: 'Mayotte',
          },
          geoCode:{
            latitude:84.2091,
            longitude:147.886
          }
          // geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: 'f14e81b4-e932-4d8e-900e-bfbff065aa0e',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc3',
          externalId: 'locId3',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:48:14.815Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add1',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Anguilla',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: '9ceb84ec-aaeb-43af-9b26-11d8ae360625',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc2',
          externalId: 'locId2',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:45:12.722Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add1',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Albania',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: '74b322b3-525f-4e76-b002-2997e9a9a8e1',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc5',
          externalId: 'locId5',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:57:41.612Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Anguilla',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: '125b0fc8-b91a-42b2-90b3-c37b9afdfa36',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc1',
          externalId: 'locId1',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:43:34.697Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add1',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Albania',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: '3375b2d3-13cd-401c-b79b-21cbdb956b15',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc7',
          externalId: 'locId7',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T04:02:11.694Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Albania',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: '76af916a-d42c-43a8-a945-3832bb9a4047',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc6',
          externalId: 'locId6',
          ownerId: 'b9e7b94f-d3a7-460d-afb7-34e277df3aec',
          owner: {
            id: 'b9e7b94f-d3a7-460d-afb7-34e277df3aec',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T04:00:02.946Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Albania',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
        {
          id: 'cf688233-f48d-4566-a4e9-5f208d6afb71',
          status: 'Incomplete',
          name: 'loc4',
          externalId: 'locId4',
          ownerId: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          owner: {
            id: 'db1a73a2-498b-43c8-9185-424cda7ea272',
          },
          orgId: 'd7d931d4-289d-49b1-bd88-29d0317b6987',
          deletedBy: null,
          deletedAt: null,
          updatedBy: null,
          updatedAt: '2021-12-15T03:53:28.203Z',
          ibLocationType: null,
          ibLocationTypeId: null,
          capacity: 0,
          phoneNumber: 0,
          address: {
            street1: 'add1',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zipCode: '',
            country: 'Albania',
          },
          geoCode: null,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

```js
const testData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(test_data); //test_data = Your data.
  }, 1000);
});
```

Now that you have a `promise` that resolves to your data, you can use it to get suggestions and results from.

```js
const customSearchSource = new SearchSource({
  placeholder: 'Search',
  getSuggestions: (params) => {
    return testData.then((data) => {
      var results = [];
      var toSearch = params.suggestTerm;
      data = data["allIBLocations"]["data"];

      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i]["name"].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
          results.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      return results.map((feature) => {
        return {
          key: "name",
          text: feature.name,
          sourceIndex: params.sourceIndex
        };
      })
    });
  },
  getResults: (params) => {
    return testData.then((data) => {
      var results = [];
      var toSearch = params.suggestResult.text;
      data = data["allIBLocations"]["data"];
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i]["name"].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
          results.push(data[i]);
        }}
      
      const searchResults = results.map((feature) => {
        console.log(feature)
        const graphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: new Point({
            latitude: feature.geoCode.latitude,
            longitude: feature.geoCode.longitude
          }),
          attributes: feature.address
        });
        const buffer = geometryEngine.geodesicBuffer(
          graphic.geometry,
          100,
          "meters"
        );
        const searchResult = {
          extent: buffer.extent,
          feature: graphic,
          name: feature["name"]
        };
        return searchResult;
      });
      return searchResults;
    });
  }
});
```

And finally set the `customSearchSource` as a source in your `searchWidget`, also disable default source to force `searchWidget` to use the source that you provide.

```js
const searchWidget = new Search({
  view: view,
  sources: [customSearchSource],
  includeDefaultSources: false
});
```

### [Live Demo](https://codepen.io/harshkaso/pen/ZEXKzvR?editors=1001)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom source with the ArcGIS JS API and add that as the source and also set the flag to [includeDefaultSources](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#includeDefaultSources) to false so it only uses yours.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-search-customsource/

With a codepen example here: https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1000

Notice here how they add the custom source made, and add it as a source to the search widget when it is instantiated.

```js
        // Create Search widget using custom SearchSource
        const searchWidget = new Search({
          view: view,
          sources: [ customSearchSource ],
          includeDefaultSources: false
        });
```

You can find the documentation on how to make a customSource here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search-SearchSource.html